# Does jetty have to use PCKS12 format? Can it use RSA certs for SSL?

Tags: jetty, keytool, pkcs#12

I have a PEM formatted RSA private key and public cert. Do I have to convert the key to PCKS12 format before I can use it with jetty? I've been searching but can't find any resources giving a straight answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the PKCS12 format for the keystore. (there's also the older JKS format)

Jetty uses Java, hence the need for PKCS12 format.

You'll have to convert your RSA private/public keys/certs to add them to a Java keystore in a format that Java understands.